# How do I add font color to my query result

Tags: html, mysql

I have a MySQL statement that returns hyper linked text. I now need it to display as blue text to show it is a link.

```
SELECT CONCAT('<a href="', opencourseware.website_url, '">', opencourseware.website_name, '</a><br />') AS Link
```

Basically I need to add this HTML somehow

```
<font color="blue">This is some text!</font>
```

It Seems like it should be so easy but I just can't get it working :( any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: seems weird to me to generate html with sql. wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT('<a style="color:blue;" href="', opencourseware.website_url, '">', opencourseware.website_name, '</a><br />') AS Link
```

Just know most browsers will display links as blue anyway ~(-_-)~

Answer (score 0):

> I have a MySQL statement that returns hyper linked text.

Why not use CSS?

```
a {
 color: #3452C9;
}
```

Also, refer to Kevin B's comment; **"seems weird to me to generate html with sql"**

Comment: I have a table pulling in a bunch of data that users submit. Part of the process is combining the data they submit into a link but for me it displays as black text. Maybe take a look at this page https://failsa.com/resource-database/mathematics/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different options. The first is to just add a class to the anchor and then put add an entry to your existing CSS file

```
SELECT CONCAT('<a href="', opencourseware.website_url, '" class="openCourseURL">'
```

and then in your CSS file for your page add *(PREFERRED)*

```
.openCourseURL{color: blue;}
```

or if you don't have a separate CSS file, add this to the head of your HTML document *(NOT PREFERRED).*

```
<style type="text/css>
    .openCourseURL{color: blue;}
</style>
```

OR you can use an inline style (but it's not considered best practice due to maintenance and rebranding concerns) *(REALLY NOT PREFERRED)*

```
SELECT CONCAT('<a href="', opencourseware.website_url, '" style="color:blue">'
```

NOTE: Typically in a web app we would like to see SQL used to get the data but not generating the HTML. HTML generation should be happening within a template engine like JSP, PHP, Handlebars, Dust, etc., as best practice.